# Question about meaning of "cargo shifted"

Tags: word-meaning

The third officer was at the helm of the ferry that capsized off South Korea, investigators said, as divers worked to access the sunken hull.A total of 268 people - including scores of high school students - remain missing after Wednesday's disaster.Twenty-eight people are now known to have died and 179 were rescued.It is not clear why the ferry sank, but experts have suggested it either hit a rock or turned sharply, unbalancing the vessel **as cargo shifted**.The vessel - named Sewol - had been travelling from Incheon, in the north-west, to the southern resort island of Jeju. It capsized and sank within a period of two hours, officials said.

As cargo shifted? As cargo moved, does it mean that? Cargo moved and then ferry became unbalaned?

Comment: Yes, the cargo moved relative to the ferry, changing its balance.

Comment: I believe that _shifted_ is the verb invariably used when cargo slides across the deck of a ship or aircraft.

Answer (score 1):

True, you nailed it.

> *...or turned sharply, unbalancing the vessel as cargo shifted.*

...means due to sharp turn, the goods that vessel was carrying moved from one place to another. The goods were *large enough in mass* that they were capable to unbalance the whole ship.

In seas, driving is very difficult and balancing a vehicle is not in just our hands (waves play crucial role) as we have better control of the vehicles on the roads.

Comment: I think I agree with JR's comment above.

Comment: @Bob - _shifting_ is used for ground vessels as well. Check out this advice from moving companies: _Loading a truck can be like a game of Tetris .. a packed moving truck will prevent items from [**shifting**](http://movinginsider.com/2012/08/14/how-to-load-a-moving-truck/). Pack items tight, like a jigsaw puzzle – all space should be filled to avoid [**shifting**](http://www.upack.com/moving-resources/loading-tips.asp).  Avoid overloading cartons, but strive for a firm pack that will prevent items from [**shifting**](http://www.unitedvanlines.com/mover/moving-aids/packing-tips.htm)._

Comment: @BobRodes and what you think went wrong with this answer?

Comment: I think I agree with this comment: "I believe that shifted is the verb invariably used when cargo slides across the deck of a ship or aircraft." At least, I can't think of any other word that would be used in such a circumstance.  I don't see anything wrong with this answer, except a couple of grammatical errors.

Comment: @BobRodes there's a simple word *move* as well! *The boxes moved from one corner to another as a vessel took a sharp turn.*

Comment: @MaulikV: Well, yes, we could say that, but generally we don't.

Comment: @JR: I agree with that comment as well.  :)